# background overlays text

Tags: html, css

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ibAMozI/1/edit)

As you can see in my jsbin the background overlays the text in my three link objects (move your cursor above it to see it).

I have tried around with the z-index (as suggested by a friend), however that doesn't seem to have any effect.

How would you go about fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
a {
    color: #CCCCCC;
 }

a:hover {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

As you can see, The font color and background color are the same on hover. The z-index has nothing to do with it. Change the `color` on `:hover` and you will see the text, as demonstrated on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yVdvx/

Answer (score 0):

Change this CSS code.

From:

```
a {
            z-index: 10000;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
            color: #CCCCCC;
            -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease;
                    transition: 0.25s ease;
        }

        a:hover {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
            opacity: .9;
            -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease;
                    transition: 0.25s ease;
        }
```

To (my example makes a:hover color blue):

```
a {
            z-index: 10000;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
            color: #CCCCCC;
            -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease;
            transition: 0.25s ease;
        }
        a:hover {
            background-color: blue;
            color: #393434;
            opacity: .9;
            -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease;
            transition: 0.25s ease;
        }
```

Besides, it may be good to include CSS code in a separate file and load it in the HTML file.